# How to view birt report in open report server?

Tags: birt

how to view the birt report on open report server after uploading birt report(.rptdesign)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you've installed the birt sample viewer and assuming, you've saved the report to the path defined as this in the web.xml:

```
<!--
    Temporary document files directory. Defaults to ${birt home}/documents
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_DOCUMENT_FOLDER</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
```

You would access the report as:

```
http://localhost:8080/birtviewer/frameset?__report=report.rptdesign
```

You can check out these for more information on how to configure it:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2685254/Installing-the-BIRT-Viewer-in-Tomcat-and-jboss

Or if you want to use tags:

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage2.2.php#tags